# How to decode unicode string that is read from a file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, utf-16, python-unicode

I have a file containing UTF-16 strings. When I try to read the unicode, " " (double quotes) are added and the string looks like `"b'\\xff\\xfeA\\x00'"`. The inbuilt `.decode` function throws a `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`. I tried a few options but those didn't work.

[This is what the file I am reading from looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RgnV.png)

Comment: Could you include what you've tried? It will make it easier to pinpoint where you need assistance.

Comment: I have tried `.decode('unicode_escape')` and encoding again and then decoding (This prints some chinese characters).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```python
str.encode().decode()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the file has been created by writing bytes literals to it, something like this:

```py
some_bytes = b'Hello world'
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(some_bytes))
```

This gets around the fact that attempting write bytes to a file opened in text mode raises an error, but at the cost that the file now contains `"b'hello world'"` (note the 'b' inside the quotes).

The solution is to decode the `bytes` to `str` before writing:

```py
some_bytes = b'Hello world'
my_str = some_bytes.decode('utf-16') # or whatever the encoding of the bytes might be
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(my_str)
```

or open the file in binary mode and write the bytes directly

```py
some_bytes = b'Hello world'
with open('myfile.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(some_bytes)
```

Note you will need to provide the correct encoding if opening the file in text mode

```
with open('myfile.txt', encoding='utf-16') as f:  # Be sure to use the correct encoding
```

Consider running Python with the `-b` or `-bb` flag set to raise a warning or exception respectively to detect attempts to stringify bytes.