# how to print a string containing utf8 code read from file

Tags: python, decode, encode

I have a file which contains UTF-8 encoded text:

```
b'\xd8\xa3\xd9\x8a \xd8\xb9\xd9\x84\xd9\x85 \xd9\x87\xd8\xb0\xd8\xa7 \xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xb0\xd9\x8a \xd9\x84\xd9\x85 \xd9\x8a\xd8\xb3\xd8\xaa\xd8\xb7\xd8\xb9 \xd8\xad\xd8\xaa\xd9\x89 \xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xa2\xd9\x86 \xd8\xa3\xd9\x86 \xd9\x8a\xd8\xb6\xd8\xb9 \xd8\xa3\xd8\xb5\xd9\x88\xd8\xa7\xd8\xaa \xd9\x85\xd9\x86 \xd9\x86\xd8\xad\xd8\xa8 \xd9\x81\xd9\x8a \xd8\xa3\xd9\x82\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb5 \xd8\x8c \xd8\xa3\xd9\x88 \xd8\xb2\xd8\xac\xd8\xa7\xd8\xac\xd8\xa9 \xd8\xaf\xd9\x88\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa1 \xd9\x86\xd8\xaa\xd9\x86\xd8\xa7\xd9\x88\xd9\x84\xd9\x87\xd8\xa7 \xd8\xb3\xd8\xb1\xd9\x91\xd9\x8b\xd8\xa7 \xd8\x8c \xd8\xb9\xd9\x86\xd8\xaf\xd9\x85\xd8\xa7 \xd9\x86\xd8\xb5\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa8 \xd8\xa8\xd9\x88\xd8\xb9\xd9\x83\xd8\xa9 \xd8\xb9\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb7\xd9\x81\xd9\x8a\xd8\xa9 \xd8\xa8\xd8\xaf\xd9\x88\xd9\x86 \xd8\xa3\xd9\x86 \xd9\x8a\xd8\xaf\xd8\xb1\xd9\x8a \xd8\xb5\xd8\xa7\xd8\xad\xd8\xa8\xd9\x87\xd8\xa7 \xd9\x83\xd9\x85 \xd9\x86\xd8\xad\xd9\x86 \xd9\x86\xd8\xad\xd8\xaa\xd8\xa7\xd8\xac\xd9\x87 - \xd8\xa3\xd8\xad\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85 \xd9\x85\xd8\xb3\xd8\xaa\xd8\xba\xd8\xa7\xd9\x86\xd9\x85\xd9\x8a, \xd8\xb9\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa8\xd8\xb1 \xd8\xb3\xd8\xb1\xd9\x8a\xd8\xb1'
```

I've tried to print it correctly once decoded but I did not succeed when:

1. reading from file as text option 'r', decode by bytes(text,'utf8').decode('utf8')
2. reading from file as binary option 'rb', decode by binary.decode('utf8')

I tried to convert the content in many ways (split text in list, cut out the b' ... ', ...) but didn't succeed to print it clearly!

What am I missing - is the file correctly 'encoded'?

Here is my code in Python 3.7.3

```
with open('/home/pi/Desktop/unicode_a_decoder.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
print(type(text),text)
#seq = text.decode
#seq = bytes(text,"utf8")
#print('seq',seq)
#seq = text
seq = text.split(" ")
#print(seq, seq[0],bytes(seq[0]))
print('seq',seq)
s0 = seq[0]
print(s0,type(s0))
s02byte = bytes(s0, 'utf8')
print(s02byte, type(s02byte))
#print(seq.decode("utf8"))
```

Comment: what language are you using? can you share the sample script you are using to printing it out?

Comment: with open('/home/pi/Desktop/unicode_a_decoder.txt', 'r') as f:
        text = f.read()
    print(type(text),text)
    #seq = text.decode
    #seq = bytes(text,"utf8")
    #print('seq',seq)
    #seq = text
    seq = text.split(" ")
    #print(seq, seq[0],bytes(seq[0]))
    print('seq',seq)
    s0 = seq[0]
    print(s0,type(s0))
    s02byte = bytes(s0, 'utf8')
    print(s02byte, type(s02byte))
    #print(seq.decode("utf8"))

my code in python 3.7.3

Comment: Pls add the code to your question by editing it. Don't use the comments..

Comment: Try ```print(text.decode('utf-8'))```.

Comment: i get an error :
print(type(text),text.decode('utf8'))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: The problem is that the file has been created incorrectly in the first place - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65169814/5320906) for example.

Comment: so i cannot create a file and push the sequence as plain text in it? I have to make a code to write a new file with the correct encoding and reread it from this new file :

some_bytes = 'b ....'
my_str = some_bytes.decode('utf8') # or whatever the encoding of the bytes might be
with open('/home/pi/Desktop/myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(my_str)
    
with open('/home/pi/Desktop/myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
        text = f.read()
print(type(text),text) 

iit works (it shows the text correctly when I open the file with an editor) but it's a bit heavy , don't you think ?

Comment: If you already have bytes then open the file in binary mode (`open('file.txt', 'wb')`) and write them directly.

Comment: thanks but this still does not answer the condition to read the sequence as plain text from a file and decode it for printing ..

Answer (score 2):

For me, it worked when I simply used `.decode()`

This is what I did:

```python
text = b'\xd8\xa3\xd9\x8a \xd8\xb9\xd9\x84\xd9\x85 \xd9\x87\xd8\xb0\xd8\xa7 \xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xb0\xd9\x8a \xd9\x84\xd9\x85 \xd9\x8a\xd8\xb3\xd8\xaa\xd8\xb7\xd8\xb9 \xd8\xad\xd8\xaa\xd9\x89 \xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xa2\xd9\x86 \xd8\xa3\xd9\x86 \xd9\x8a\xd8\xb6\xd8\xb9 \xd8\xa3\xd8\xb5\xd9\x88\xd8\xa7\xd8\xaa \xd9\x85\xd9\x86 \xd9\x86\xd8\xad\xd8\xa8 \xd9\x81\xd9\x8a \xd8\xa3\xd9\x82\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb5 \xd8\x8c \xd8\xa3\xd9\x88 \xd8\xb2\xd8\xac\xd8\xa7\xd8\xac\xd8\xa9 \xd8\xaf\xd9\x88\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa1 \xd9\x86\xd8\xaa\xd9\x86\xd8\xa7\xd9\x88\xd9\x84\xd9\x87\xd8\xa7 \xd8\xb3\xd8\xb1\xd9\x91\xd9\x8b\xd8\xa7 \xd8\x8c \xd8\xb9\xd9\x86\xd8\xaf\xd9\x85\xd8\xa7 \xd9\x86\xd8\xb5\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa8 \xd8\xa8\xd9\x88\xd8\xb9\xd9\x83\xd8\xa9 \xd8\xb9\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb7\xd9\x81\xd9\x8a\xd8\xa9 \xd8\xa8\xd8\xaf\xd9\x88\xd9\x86 \xd8\xa3\xd9\x86 \xd9\x8a\xd8\xaf\xd8\xb1\xd9\x8a \xd8\xb5\xd8\xa7\xd8\xad\xd8\xa8\xd9\x87\xd8\xa7 \xd9\x83\xd9\x85 \xd9\x86\xd8\xad\xd9\x86 \xd9\x86\xd8\xad\xd8\xaa\xd8\xa7\xd8\xac\xd9\x87 - \xd8\xa3\xd8\xad\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85 \xd9\x85\xd8\xb3\xd8\xaa\xd8\xba\xd8\xa7\xd9\x86\xd9\x85\xd9\x8a, \xd8\xb9\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa8\xd8\xb1 \xd8\xb3\xd8\xb1\xd9\x8a\xd8\xb1'
print(text.decode())
```

Comment: yes i noticed it already but how to do if my sequence MUST be read from a file !!!!